# Add a column to a database with matching values from another database r

Tags: r, aggregate, cbind

Sorry that my question is a little vague. I have two separated data bases (data1 as the first database and data2 as the second one) as follows:

```
      Area  Yr    AllRev                 Totalcalls
      A    2012  1021597.78             835
      B    2013  1002968.21             833
      c    2014   730345.93             65
      d    2015   251956.26             232
      e    2012    22408.71              25
      ...
```

Data 2:

```
      Yr   TotRev               TotCalls
      2012 160038596.0          131064
      2013 399750664.0          312651
      ...
```

Now I want to add a column "RevPercent" to data 1 which is going to calculate the following value for each row:

```
    100*data1$AllRev/data2$TotRev
```

However, if yr ==2012 for data1, I want it to read TotRev for 2012 from data2 to calculate the aformentioned value. I wrote the following line of code but I definitely am getting an error:

```
    data1 <- cbind(data1,100*round(data1[,3]/data2[data2[,1]==data2[,2],2],4))
```

And the error is as follows:
        In data2[, 1] == data2[,2] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object leng

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't the answer to this just be "merge (by year) then calculate"?

Comment: I can do a merge but thought there might be a way without merging.

Comment: Surely, but it would involve using `data2$TotRev[ match(data1$Yr, data2$Yr) ]` since `match`  is what `merge` uses under the hood. I think the code using `merge` will be clearer. The code using `match` to generate an index for selecting from a different vector is a bit more difficult for most people to grasp when they first see it. There are many worked examples on SO. Do some searching.